# Jquery copy selected text from paragraph to input on button click (multiple inputs)

Tags: jquery, text, input, copy, selection

I have situation for professionals here, plus I don't have one line of jquery code writen... I have text paragraph and three input fields matched with buttons... My wish is that on selection of text in paragraph you could get this same selection as value in wished input when you click on button copy.
I've searched web and did not find something similar to that stuff

I have js fiddle with html only and you could update it: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/5DKuY/

HTML:

```
    <p>
Aliquam eget ipsum accumsan, convallis nulla sit amet, auctor est. 
Nam quis condimentum eros, vel condimentum lacus. In id enim at sem 
gravida sodales eu vitae risus. Morbi sed mi sit amet lectus rhoncus 
gravida a sit amet nisl. Phasellus quis ultricies leo. Duis vel lobortis
mauris. Suspendisse sed diam eu turpis facilisis rutrum vitae vitae
dolor. 
</p>

<form id="myform" class="form-horizontal">
    </fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <input type="text" class="input-small" id="input1">
            <a href="#" id="copy1" class="btn btn-primary">Copy to 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <input type="text" class="input-small" id="input2">
            <a href="#" id="copy2" class="btn btn-primary">Copy to 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
        <input type="text" class="input-small" id="input2">
        <a href="#" id="copy2" class="btn btn-primary">Copy to 3</a>
        </div>
    </fieldset>  
</form>
```

Is that even possible? or it could be solved on somewhat different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
// Get user selection text on page
function getSelectedText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return '';
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#copy1').click(function () {
        $('#input1').val(getSelectedText());
    });
    $('#copy2').click(function () {
        $('#input2').val(getSelectedText());
    });
    $('#copy3').click(function () {
        $('#input3').val(getSelectedText());
    });
});
```

And the [jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/8WbRu/) with the working example.

Comment: man! that works! I tried something with range but didn't acomplish it... That's ace! thank you so much! :)